# How to call a php function from another php file

Tags: php

I have two php files, one index.php

```
<?php
    include ‘Play.php’;
    $temp = first(HH);
    echo $temp;
?>
```

second Play.php

```
<?php
    function first($string)
    { 
            return $string;  
    }
?>
```

if i remove $temp = first(HH); from the first file then it works, if i include it, the index.php don't work (don't show anything on the screen when i call it within safari.

I know its going to be obvious but what am i doing wrong? Both files are in the same file directory.

Thanks

Comment: Set `error_reporting` and `display_errors` so you see what you are doing wrong. And quote 'HH'

Comment: *Ah*, yet another code with funky quotes `‘ ’`. "*Beautiful, yet deadly*."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the right kind of quotes around your string for the include. `"` or `'` not `‘` and `’`.

The use of typographic quotes like that suggests you may be trying to write code with a word processor. Don't do that; get a text or code editor instead.

Comment: and thats why working in early hours is never a good thing, can't believe i missed that thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function is right but the way you are calling your function is not correct.And the way you are including the file is incorrect. You should include your file in quotes like `""` or `''` . You have to enclose the string in quotes `""`. Use the code below in index.php

```
<?php
    include 'Play.php';
    $temp = first("HH");
    echo $temp;
?>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: the quote marks in the `include` are still wrong in this example, they need to be single or double, not back ticks

Comment: Oh sorry i did it by mistake

Answer (score 1):

`include` expects double quotes `"` so change that in, your code and it should work.
`include "Play.php";`

Answer (score -2):

Kindly change 
$temp = first(HH); to  $temp = first("HH");

its is  because your function tack string as a parameter you should send a string